# What can happend if I am sexting with an underage girl from another country?

Tags: internet, civil-law, police

So I met this girl on the internet and I told her I am 19 and she told me she is 17. We started talking for a while and she sent me me a pic in underwear.. We started texting and all that.. we did this for a couple of times.
After a while she told me she is 15..I know that is not legal even if she was 17.. so she told me she is 15.
What would happen if we keep doing it. 
Could something happen if we just talk normally without any sexual terms.

I am from Europe and she is from US. more exactly California .. so another continent.
Could I be charged or something..?

Comment: Are you 19? (You've said that's what you told her, but not whether this was accurate, and this might affect any charges that could be brought.) Either way, make sure you read up on "sextortion" - the scenario you describe fits with previous accounts of the early stages of blackmail.

Answer (score 3):

The definitive answer to the question "could I be charged" is always YES.

I refer you to [the Manassas City teen charged with child pornography](https://rewire.news/article/2014/07/10/virginia-teen-sexted-girlfriend-faces-child-pornography-charges-forced-photograph-penis/).

> Child pornography laws were put in place to protect children and
>   prevent them from being exploited by having sexual pictures of them
>   taken and distributed. In this case, the picture in question is of the
>   young man’s own genitals, which would make him both the perpetrator
>   and the victim.

Apparently the lead detective in the Manassas City teen's case was himself a [pedophile](https://wtvr.com/2015/12/16/david-abbott-arrest/) and just wanted an excuse to use force to photograph the teen's erect penis.

Why would you assume this "girl" is a "17 year old girl" or a "15 year old girl" and not a 39 year old pedophile Manassas police officer?

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. It's always wise to assume people on the internet may not be who they say they are.